z transform for high pass filter
Starting with the Laplace transform of the impulse response of a high pass CR filter I get
$$H(s)=\frac{s}{s+\omega_\tau}$$ that gives a pole on the negative real axis $-\omega_\tau$ and a zero at $0$. Using the bilinear transform approximation this tells me that in the z-plane I expect a pole at $$z=\frac{1-\omega_\tau\frac{T}{2}}{1+\omega_\tau\frac{T}{2}}$$ and a zero at $z=1$.  However
$H(z) = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}  (\delta(nT) - {1\over RC} e^{-{nT\over RC}} u(nT)) z^{-n} = {1 - \omega_\tau - e^{-\omega_\tau T} z^{-1} \over 1 - e^{-\omega_\tau T} z^{-1} }
$
Does not produce the right result because as @Matt has pointed out the dirac delta function does not work inside a sum.  My updated question is what does work?  How can I derive the z-transform for a high pass filter using $$Z[r(t)] = R(z) = \sum^\infty_{n=-\infty} r(nT) z^{-n}$$
Just to clarify I am looking for a solution along the lines of my z-transform for low pass filter.

You compare the results to two different methods for converting a continuous-time system to a discrete-time system. The bilinear transform is different from the impulse invariant transformation.
The bilinear transform is a mapping (Moebius transformation) from the $s$-plane to the $z$-plane, whereas with the impulse invariant transformation, the discrete-time impulse response is obtained by sampling the continuous-time impulse response.
Another problem is that for the given filter, you can't use the impulse invariant method because the continuous-time filter has a Dirac delta in its impulse response, which you can't sample. You seem to have used $\delta(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$ (which is okay, if interpreted correctly), but you also used $\delta(0)=1$, which is wrong because the Dirac delta impulse doesn't have a value at zero argument.
In sum, there are many ways to transform a continuous-time system to a discrete-time system, and in general they all result in different systems. Second, in your specific case you can't apply the impulse invariant method because of the nature of the continuous-time impulse response.
EDIT:
The bilinear transform will work for your first-order highpass filter. The transfer function of a continuous-time first-order RC highpass filter is
$$H_c(s)=\frac{s}{s+1/\tau},\qquad \tau=RC\tag{1}$$
Using the mapping of the bilinear transform
$$s=k\frac{z-1}{z+1}\tag{2}$$
with some positive constant $k$ results in the following transfer function of the corresponding discrete-time highpass filter:
$$H(z)=H_c\left(k\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)=\frac{k}{k+1/\tau}\frac{z-1}{z-\frac{k-1/\tau}{k+1/\tau}}\tag{3}$$
The constant $k$ can be chosen such that a given frequency $\Omega_0$ in the continuous domain is mapped to a desired frequency $\omega_0$ in the discrete domain, where $\omega_0$ is normalized by the sampling frequency:
$$k=\frac{\Omega_0}{\tan(\omega_0/2)}\tag{4}$$
The plot below shows a comparison of the two frequency responses. I chose $\tau=RC=1$, a sampling interval $T=0.5$ and a reference frequency $\Omega_0=0.2\pi/T$. Of course, the approximation can be improved by choosing a smaller sampling interval.

Note that there are several other methods for transforming a continuous-time system to the discrete domain, as explained in this answer. However, for continuous-time transfer functions that are not strictly proper (as is the case for highpass filters), the impulse invariant method cannot be used.

Thanks for your response.. I note that there are multiple tables with common z-transform pairs for example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/common-z-transform-pairs where the z-transform of  my discrete time transform is documented as X(\delta(nT)) = 1 for all z.  Also the bilinear transform is simply an approximation derived from taking the natural log of each side of e^{sT} = z (the definition of the z in the z-transform), so is simply an an approximation of ln(z). So I am not entirely sure that your conclusions are correct.

@Pete: You're confusing the discrete-time Kronecker delta $\delta[n]$ with the continuous-time Dirac delta impulse $\delta(t)$, which share the same symbol $\delta$. The inverse Laplace transform of $1$ is not (and cannot) be the same as the inverse Z-transform of $1$. I'm aware of the derivation of the bilinear transform, but I'm not sure how this would disagree with my statement that the bilinear transform doesn't result in the same discrete-time system as the impulse invariant transform (which - als already mentioned - is not applicable in your case).

agreed I am confused.. Also I do not think that I am closer to understanding how to derive the z-transform for my simple high pass filter.

@Pete: Well, I think you already did, using the bilinear transform. You also tried via sampling the continuous-time impulse response, but that doesn't work for that filter. Help me understand what it is that is still unclear.

I get your point about the dirac delta function.  It does work in the Laplace transform because the dirac delta function does work inside an integral.  I have to read about impulse invariant transform because I do not understand that part of your comment.  Regardless of these things I was hoping to get an exact derivation of the z-transform for the high pass filter in the same way I have managed to get an exact derivation of the z-transform for the low pass filter case.  It seems from what you say that I have to be satisfied with an approximation.

@Pete: The point is that there is no "exact" transformation from continuous-time to discrete-time. Can you define what you mean by exact?
The impulse invariant method simply samples the continuous-time impulse response. That is what I thought you tried to do when looking at your formula for $H(z)$.

The bilinear transform result in frequency warping (because the infinite frequency axis is mapped to a circle), and the impulse invariant method results in aliasing. You have to choose which artefact you prefer.

my "exact" comment was based on the taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ that I used to derive my z-transform for the low pass case.  What I am looking for is something similar to derive the z-transform for the high pass case.

@Pete: It would be great if you could add your derivation of the z-transform of a first-order lowpass filter to your question.

I suspect that would be a whole new question - here is a version - https://www.dummies.com/article/business-careers-money/careers/trades-tech-engineering-careers/working-across-domains-example-take-the-rc-low-pass-filter-to-the-z-domain-165340/

@Pete: That's the impulse invariant method. I've updated my answer by adding how to use the bilinear transform for your filter.

Thank you very much for adding this detail... the bilinear transformation only takes the first term in a series for ln(x) $$sT = \ln z = 2 \left( {z-1\over z+1} + \frac{1}{3}\left({z-1\over z+1}\right)^3 + \frac{1}{5}\left({z-1\over z+1}\right)^5 + \cdots \right) \text{\ where\ }0\lt z$$ so I am actually looking for something that is a bit more accurate.

@Pete: Well, you have the series, so you could use higher order terms if you wanted to. Just give it a try. However, I don't think that you'd gain a lot. First, you could choose a smaller sampling interval $T$ (a higher sampling frequency) to improve the approximation. Second, you usually don't want to create a high-order filter from a low-order analog filter; even using only one more term in the series would triple the filter order of the digital filter. Also, if for some reason you don't like the result of the bilinear transform, there are still several other methods to choose from.

see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/95717/z-transform-for-low-pass-filter for my low pass derivation
