z transform for low pass filter
I recently asked a question about z transform for a high pass filter and in the process decided that I may have got the wrong derivation for the low pass filter.  Please let me know if this derivation is good and if not supply suitable hits about how to improve it!
First from an earlier post about the impulse response for a CR circuit I derive the impulse response for a low pass RC circuit, then, using a Taylor series, derive the z-transform.
impulse response for an RC circuit
Based on an earlier similar solution
Assuming zero initial conditions the current at the output node of a RC circuit is given by:
$$\begin{aligned}{x(t) - y(t)\over R} &= C{d\over dt}y(t) \\
{d\over dt}y(t) + \omega_\tau y(t) &= \omega_\tau x(t)
\end{aligned}$$
The impulse response of the circuit is determined by solving this equation when a delta function is applied to the input ($x(t) = \delta(t)$).  I assume that the $\delta(t)$ function is unchanged by any real multiplier ie $x(t) = \delta(t) = \omega_\tau\delta(t)$. A potential solution for $y(t)$ is $y_p(t) = K e^{-t\omega_\tau}$.. a good starting point however has the problem that for large negative times $e^{-t\omega_\tau}$ becomes very large.  We can improve on this potential solution by ensuring that for all negative times $y_a(t) = 0$ using the unit step function that can be differentiated
$$\begin{aligned}u(t) &= \begin{cases}     0      & \quad t < 0 \\
     1 & \quad 0 \le t  
   \end{cases} \\
y_a(t) &= K e^{-t\omega_\tau} u(t) \\
{d\over dt}y_a(t) &= K u(t) {d\over dt} e^{-t\omega_\tau}  + K e^{-t\omega_\tau} {d\over dt} u(t) \\
{d\over dt}y_a(t) &= -K\omega_\tau u(t) e^{-t\omega_\tau}  + K e^{-t\omega_\tau} \delta(t) = \delta(t) - K\omega_\tau u(t) e^{-t\omega_\tau} = \delta(t) -\omega_\tau y_a(t)\\
{d\over dt}y_a(t) + \omega_\tau y_a(t) &=  \delta(t) = \omega_\tau x(t)
\end{aligned}$$
This is good for times $t \ne 0$.  Basically it is a mathematical expression of the steady state where provided the input is not changing the capacitor $C$ discharges through the resistor with a time constant ($\tau = RC$).  From the physical point of view it is clear that the impulse applied to the $RC$ circuit at $t = 0$ will charge the capacitor to some value and immediately after when $x = 0$ the output will be a positive value that will gradually return to $0$ over time discharging through the resistor ($x(t \gt 0) = 0$).
Using this solution for the RC circuit I provide a solution for the transfer function $h(t)$ of the RC circuit as follows.  At time $t = 0 + \Delta$ the output $y(\Delta) = h(\Delta) = {1\over RC}$ ie $K = 1$. At time $t = 0 - \Delta$ the output $y(-\Delta) = h(-\Delta) =  0$
$$h(t) = \omega_\tau e^{-t\omega_\tau} u(t)
$$
z-transform for low pass filter based on the RC circuit
Based on Stephen Roberts Lecture 2
First the sampling part using a sample interval of $T$... The Laplace transform of a unit impulse occuring at time $t=kT$, for some value of integer $k$ (in the bilateral case $k$ may be positive or negative), is the convolution $F(s) = \int^\infty_{-\infty} \delta(t - T) e^{-s t}dt = e^{-sT}$.  Suppose we construct a discrete function $f[kT]$ from a succession of these impulses then the Laplace transform of the function is
$$F_d(s) = f[0] + f[1T]e^{-Ts} + f[2T]e^{-2Ts} + f[3T]e^{-3Ts} + \dots +f[kT]e^{-kTs}
$$
We can re-write this using $z = e^{sT} = e^{\sigma T} e^{j\omega T}$ to introduce the z-transform of the function $f[kT]$
$$F(z) = f[0]+ f[1T]z^{-1} + f[2T]z^{-2} + f([3T]z^{-3} + \dots +f[kT]z^{-k} = \sum^k_{k=0}f[kT]z^{-k}
$$
Bringing it all together we use the Taylor series
$$\frac{1}{1-p^{-1}} = p^0 + p^{-1} + p^{-2}\cdots = \sum^\infty_{k=0}p^{-k}\ \text{if}\  \lvert p^{-1}\rvert\lt 1
$$
$$H(z) = \sum^k_{k=0}h[kT]z^{-k} = \omega_\tau\sum^\infty_{k=-\infty} e^{-kT\omega_\tau} u(kT)z^{-k} = \frac{\omega_\tau}{1-e^{-T\omega_\tau}z^{-1}}
$$
where the unit step function $u(Tk)$ is used to ensure that the sum is zero for all negative $k$

Your result is correct, up to a constant factor (explained below). The derivation in the frequency domain would have been a bit more straightforward, as shown here.
In the Laplace transform domain we can directly write down the transfer function of a first-order RC lowpass filter:
$$H_c(s)=\frac{1/sC}{R+1/sC}=\frac{1}{\tau}\frac{1}{s+1/\tau},\qquad \tau=RC\tag{1}$$
The impulse response is the inverse Laplace transform of $(1)$ given by
$$h_c(t)=\frac{1}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}u(t)\tag{2}$$
Sampling $(2)$ at $t=nT$ and scaling results in
$$h[n]=Th_c(nT)=\frac{T}{\tau}e^{-nT/\tau}u[n]\tag{3}$$
The transfer function of the discrete-time filter is given by the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $(3)$:
$$H(z)=\frac{T}{\tau}\frac{1}{1-e^{-T/\tau}z^{-1}}\tag{4}$$
The necessity of the scaling constant $T$ is explained in this answer.
There are two things to note here; first, if the impulse response of the continuous-time filter contains Dirac impulses, we cannot use this method ("impulse invariance"), because we cannot sample a Dirac impulse. The impulse response has a Dirac impulse (and possibly its derivatives) if the transfer function is not strictly proper, as is the case with highpass and bandstop filters. Second, we were a bit sloppy when sampling $h_c(t)$ because the impulse response is discontinuous at $t=0$, and we should have used the average of the left-sided and right-sided limits, which is half the value we used in $(3)$. This way of dealing with discontinuities of the continuous-time impulse response is referred to as "corrected impulse invariance" and it is briefly explained in this answer.
